# Overlapping points when drawing data from serial port

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port

I am trying to draw some data sent by an arduino, using a serial port, and matplotlib. I accomplish to do this and i can draw the data in a maptplolib figure.

This is my code:

```
class ViewWidget(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)

    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

    self.x = []

def Data(self):
    print "Opening port"
    port = "com4"
    arduinoData = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
    ViewWidget.list_of_ports.append(arduinoData)

    while True:
        if arduinoData.inWaiting()>0:
            arduinoString = arduinoData.read(arduinoData.inWaiting())
            ardString = map(ord, arduinoString)

            for number in ardString:
                numb = float(number/77.57)
                self.x.append(numb)
                drawnow(self.makeFig)

                if len(self.x)>50:
                    self.x.pop(0)

        else:
            print "There is no data"

def makeFig(self):
    self.axes.plot(self.x, picker = 5)
    self.figure_canvas.draw()
```

The problem is that when it starts to draw the data in the plot, after a few seconds, it starts to show overlapping points and after a brief time, it crashes and it stops drawing, as you can see here:

[image]

I think the problem comes when i use the `self.x.pop(0)` line, but i do not know why.

What am i doing wrong? Could the problem be the `drawnow` module?.Hope you can help me.